# So I have 3 different columns in a excel file, what I need to is convert rows into columns by reference_number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have columns like this,

| REF_NO | LCY_AMOUNT | TAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 200 | NEGO |
| 001 | 300 | EXCH |
| 001 | 350 | POST |
| 001 | 400 | CONF |
| 002 | 300 | NEGO |
| 002 | 400 | EXCH |
| 002 | 450 | POST |
| 002 | 500 | CONF |

What I need is Tag rows into columns like this

| REF_NO | NEGO | EXCH | POST | CONF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 200 | 300 | 350 | 400 |
| 002 | 300 | 400 | 450 | 500 |

Comment: You can do this with Power Query. Pivot rows to columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So went with sumifs():

```
SUMIFS($B$3:$B$10,$A$3:$A$10,$A15,$C$3:$C$10,B$14)
```

[image]

And to produce the values in A15 and A16, you can check out unique().